# Why does flex-basis default to 0 when omitted in the shorthand flex notation?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

Since the initial value of `flex-basis` is `auto`, I expected the property to default to `auto` if omitted in a shorthand notation like this:

`flex: 2 1;` instead it defaults to `0` !

What's the reason, why it behaves like that?

Answer (score 4):

When omitted in the shorthand notation, `flex-basis` does not always default to `0`. For example:

- In `flex : initial` (`0 1 auto`), the `flex-basis` component has a value of `auto`.
- In `flex: none` (`0 0 auto`), the `flex-basis` component has a value of `auto`.
- In `flex: auto` (`1 1 auto`), the `flex-basis` component has a value of `auto`.

So why does `flex-basis` have a value of `0` when preceded by two flex factors? The spec doesn't explain. [It just says](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-basis), *"When omitted from the `flex` shorthand, its specified value is `0`."*

My best guess at this time would be this: Considering that the other three `flex` values resolve to `flex-basis: auto`, perhaps spec authors wanted to provide developers with one option where the value defaulted to `0`.

More:

- [§ 7.1.1. Basic Values of `flex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: To make it easy to resize items according to a fixed ratio.

This question only becomes relevant if your flex container has multiple items. In that case, it is a common idiom to set `flex: N` for some or even all of them. The natural expectation is that the items without this setting keep their size (hence, the default of `flex-grow` is `0`) while the others are sized according to the ratio defined by `flex-grow`. By natural, I mean that `flex; 1`, `flex: 2`, `flex: 1` naturally corresponds to the ratio 1:2:1. If `flex: N` were to default to `flex-basis: auto`, this expectation could be violated:

```
 <div style="width:100px;height:100px;display:flex">
    <div style="width:10%;flex:1;border:1px solid black"></div>
    <div style="flex:1;border:1px solid black"></div>
</div>
```

Instead of both items sharing the space equally, one item is `55px` wide and the other `45px`.

This begs the question: Why set a width at all (like `width: 10%`) if you want flex to distribute it anyway? I surmise that this makes it more beginner-friendly and less error-prone.

However, once you've understood how `flex-base` works, I agree that it can be confusing (that's how I stumbled upon this question...).